# Bootable External Hard Drive Windows 10 while have Files

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, bootable-media, rufus

It is possible my external hard drive to become bootable windows 10 while it have files like videos, music, document?

Comment: Do you want windows 10 setup or a full version of running windows?

Comment: @Pancakedinner i download windows 10 setup sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. (How big is your Harddrive? How much space do you have left?)

you will need to create a partition.
This means you can install windows on your 2nd partition you just created.
depending what you want Windows for, You will probably want 50GB - 100GB for your 2nd partition, depending on what you want it for. You can always change it later.

Comment: partition is in disk management sir?

Comment: Yes, You can look at some guides to get an idea of how to do it. (if you never have done it before) https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-partition-a-hard-drive-2626081